# Where is the place for altering validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Sometimes I need not to simply validate smth in my app, but also alter it before/after validating.
I.e.

```
 class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_url
  ...
  private
  def validate_url
    url = "rtmp://#{url}" if server_url[0..6] != "rtmp://" #alter cause need this prefix 
    unless /rtmp:\/\/[a-z0-9]{1,3}\.pscp\.tv:80\/[a-z0-9]\/[a-z0-9]{1,3}\//.match url
      errors.add(:url, "...")
    end
  end
end
```

or smth like this

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_restreams
  ...
  private
  def validate_restreams
    self.left_restreams = self.left_restreams - self.restreams #to be sure there's no intersections
  end
end
```

But I feel it's not a right place for such things, so I need to know what's the way to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator for a rails model. You should make a class, inherit it from `ActiveModel::Validator`, and define a `validate(record)` method there, which will add errors to the record. For example:

This is your validator class:

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless url_valid?(record[:url])
      record.errors.add(:url, 'is invalid')
    end
  end

  private

  def url_valid?(url)
    # validate url and return bool
  end
end
```

And now simply add this to the model:

```
validates_with MyValidator
```

Comment: Oh, that's not the answer I expected to get. I mean changing the value is not what you usually expect from validator, right? So, maybe there's another way to do the same?..